# how to run a test of selenium in jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

I figured out how to run a test of an application without eclipse using `right click on the project->export->as runnable jar` and to run the test I used the terminal and typed `java -jar $file.jar` but the problem comes when I tried the same command on jenkins, the console output is the following:

```
    Starting OperaDriver 2.42.3135 (O58) on port 20597
    Only local connections are allowed.
    [1554121442.540][SEVERE]: bind() returned an error, errno=0: Cannot assign requested address (99)
        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
        Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
        Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
        System info: host: 'localhost.localdomain', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64', java.version: '11.0.2'
        Driver info: driver.version: OperaDriver
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:202)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:188)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
            at org.openqa.selenium.opera.OperaDriver.<init>(OperaDriver.java:173)
            at org.openqa.selenium.opera.OperaDriver.<init>(OperaDriver.java:160)
            at org.openqa.selenium.opera.OperaDriver.<init>(OperaDriver.java:149)
            at com.star.Simulation.Demo.testMethod(Demo.java:25)
            at com.star.Simulation.Demo.main(Demo.java:42)
            ... 5 more
        Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:20597/status] to be available after 20032 ms
            at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:197)
            ... 15 more
        Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204)
            at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:148)
            at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
            ... 16 more
        [SSH] completed
        [SSH] exit-status: 1

        Build step 'Execute shell script on remote host using ssh' marked build as failure
        /*Sending e-mails to: some@mail
        ERROR: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25
        javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
          nested exception is:
            java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
            at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)
            at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
            at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
            at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
            at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
            at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
            at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
            at hudson.tasks.MailSender.run(MailSender.java:131)
            at hudson.tasks.Mailer.perform(Mailer.java:173)
            at hudson.tasks.Mailer.perform(Mailer.java:136)
            at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
            at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
            at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
            at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
            at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
            at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1843)
            at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
            at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
            at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
        Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
            at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
            at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
            at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
            at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
            at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
            at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
            at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:286)
            at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:231)
            at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1900)
            ... 18 more
this error is normal because I didn't configure the smtp server*/ 
        Finished: FAILURE
```

can you point me to the right direction? thanks in advance
if you require additional information I can provide them, just ask

Comment: Is it must to run it as a jar or this is the way you choose? Did you tried it without jar and with maven?

Comment: I supposed that the person who will respond has read my previous question but I will explain again: I have problems using the code `java -cp lib/*:bin org.testng.TestNG testng.xml so my solution was to export a jar file and run it but I ran into problem

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution: open the terminal and go to the project directory, before doing anything, add the selenium, testng and java compiler plugins in your pom.xml (you can find everything on maven repository website) , download the opera webdriver and install opera in your system, then add this code in your class :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", "path/to/your/operadriver");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.logfile", "any/path/to/operadriver.log");
    OperaOptions options = new OperaOptions();
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    options.addArguments("disable-setuid-sandbox");
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
    options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
    options.addArguments("--headless");
    options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
    WebDriver driver = new OperaDriver(options);
```

then on the terminal use this command (you have to install maven and java obviously):

```
mvn compile test
```

that's it

Comment: oh and make sure you have no opera or opera webdriver process open